# Batman's helmet in Superman vs Batman

Tags: dc, superman, batman

In the new trailer for Superman vs Batman, it looks like Batman is wearing an armor type helmet with eyes that glow or light up in some fashion. Has this type of helmet shown up in any Batman stories previously? I will accept any examples from comics, TV shows, cartoons, or movies.

[image]

Comment: Bears a more-than-passing resemblance to [the powered armour he uses to fight Superman in "The Dark Knight Returns"](http://static.srcdn.com/slir/w700-h350-q90-c700:350/wp-content/uploads/Batman-V-Superman-Dark-Knight-Returns-Armor.jpg)

Comment: @JasonBaker That image looks like a pretty good example. Could be the start of a good answer.

Comment: @Whovian4Life - I took the liberty of adding a photo to your question.  Hope you don't mind.

Comment: Related: http://io9.com/all-the-reasons-why-batman-has-worn-power-armor-1699426752

Comment: @wadcheber Thanks. The picture adds to the question. I'm still kind of new here and trying to figure things out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### It's not just a helmet. It's part of a suit of armor which makes its first appearance in [The Dark Knight Returns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Knight_Returns). It is likely the very inspiration for the current suit appearing in Batman v Superman.

> The Dark Knight Returns is set in a dystopian near-future version of Gotham City. Bruce Wayne, at 55, has retired from crime-fighting for ten years. Levels of crime are rising. Wayne has a breakthrough and finds retirement is against his instincts and becomes Batman again.

Wayne creates this suit to confront a weakened Superman who has come to confront Batman at the behest of the government. Superman regrets this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hell, based on the trailer, DoJ is DKR almost verbatim

Comment: "Superman regrets this." It still makes me laugh how Batman faking a heart attack seconds after knocking Superman over is still somehow classed as a major victory for Batman after all this time.

Comment: @DrRDizzle - how so? He didn't fake the heart attack to stop the fight or to get away from Superman. He faked his death so that the government would stop coming after him. As for the fight itself, he literally had Clark at his mercy and could have killed him if he wanted to. His plan was to put Clark in his place, not kill him... and in that regard, the fight was a success on all counts. That's pretty clearly a victory.